# "Extreme" consequences of argument

Tags: nuance, philosophy

I am trying to say that an argument (a philosophical reasoning for what it's worth) is not taken to its extreme consequences, in the sense that it is not brought and explored to its logical deepest reach. A reach that, here's my point, would be logically (rectius: epistemically) unacceptable and therefore impairs the overall soundness of the argument.

At the same time, every kind of dictionary daunts me in saying "the resoning is not taken to its extreme consequences" for it would give the whole phrase a appraisive tone, since "extreme" is not only a logical height (i.e., when collecting the reasoning's every possible declension) but also some sort of moral value (the reasoning is "extreme" in the sense that it is not moderate, it lacks equilibrium, it's kind of... violent). Now, I definitely want to avoid any of that moral fashion in my statement. How should one say, then, "to explore a reasoning in all its implications and reach" in a normal unconvoluted manner?

Comment: Can you express your question in a less arcane and convoluted way? This is very dense language, and hard for non-philosophers to understand (and therefore to answer). Failing that, might [Philosophy.SE] be a more appropriate place to ask?

Comment: I'll do my best. Basically you're talking to a friend. He says: "I think every death penalty supporter should be prosecuted to the full extent of the law". And you say: "then, if the law has death penalty as hardest punishment, should you inflict the death penalty". He says: "you're having fun of me". You: "no, i'm just *taking your reasoning to its extreme consequences*". Now what's the right way to say that? It just doesn't sound right to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you say you don't like the following sentence:

> I'm just taking your reasoning to its extreme consequences.

The use of *extreme consequences* is not very idiomatic, even regardless of your mention of not liking its possible judgment of moral values.

When talking about an argument and its possible end result, we would normally say:

> I'm just taking your reasoning to its **logical conclusion**.

Answer (score 0):

****going, carry or take to extremes****  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/extreme)  idiom

> 1. To take drastic measures toward some goal or end. the type to go to extremes to get what he wants.
> 2. To act in an excessive or overzealous manner.

As in:

I'm just taking your reasoning to its extremes.